# SQL Server: How to generate a reference column with data that increments?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

t1 and t2.

t1 has an ID and a Reference. The format of that reference is TO-0000000 which cannot exceed 7 characters.

t2 has 1500 records. How do insert that data with an incremented count?

T2 doesn't contain a reference field. T2 contains an ID which has 1500 records. I want to import that ID or even just loop a count to 1500 and generate a reference.

For example

```
ID    Reference
1     TO-0000001
..    ......
1500  TO-0001500
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You should normally just store data in a natural representation in the database and leave formatting concerns out. If you want consistency, you might consider adding a computed column that does the formatting - but I'd still be *storing* the data as just 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would be inclined to agree but there's an existing schema and system in place which forces me to re-write scripts in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to import the `ID` column to T1 and also generate a reference field when inserting that data. If that is the case, then try this:

```
INSERT INTO T1 (ID,Reference)
SELECT ID,'TO-'+Left('0000000',(7-LEN(ID)))+CAST(ID AS CHAR)
FROM T2
```

Try executing this in SSMS for easier understanding

```
DECLARE @num int=1
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
ID INT,
Reference Char(10)
)
WHILE @num <= 1500
BEGIN
Insert INTO @Results
Select @num, 'TO-'+Left('0000000',(7-LEN(@num)))+CAST(@num AS CHAR)
SET @num = @num+1
END
SELECT * FROM @Results
```

Comment: Raj, this is perfect. Well written and easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make ID column of table t1 as `IDENTITY` and increment will automatically be taken care of.
Now you only need to extarct refernces values from source table t2 and insert into target table t1.

```
INSERT INTO t1(References)
SELECT References FROM t2
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was clear. T2 doesn't contain a reference field. T2 contains an ID which has 1500 records. I want to import that ID or even just loop a count to 1500 and generate a reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Flag INT IDENTITY(1,1),Name VARCHAR(20));
DECLARE @N INT,@name VARCHAR(20)
SET @N = 1
WHILE (@N < 1500)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @T(Name)
VALUES( 'TO' + RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@N),12));
SET @N = @N + 1;

END
select * from @T
```